# How to call Java Action using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struct

I am new to AJAX. I am having two drop drop list in JSP, based on selecting one value from first drop down, I need to populate values in second drop down list from Back End.
I have tried to do the above functionality from AJAX in **struct1.2**.

I have used following Code inside onChangePrdGrp[**JavaScript Function**]:

```
var prdGrp = document.getElementById('strProductGroup').value;
if("" != prdGrp){
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    document.getElementById('prdPitch').style.display = "block";
    document.forms[0].module.value= "getProductPicthed";
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/lmsGetPrdPitched.do?prdGrp="+prdGrp,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}else{
    document.getElementById('prdPitch').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('strProductPitched').value = "";
    document.getElementById('strProduct').value = "";
}
```

DropDown1:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left" width="20%">Product Group</td>
<td style="text-align: left" width="20%"><html:select
property="strProductGroup" style="width:180px;"
onchange="onChangePrdGrp()">
<html:option value="">select</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection name="ProdGrpList" />
</html:select></td>
</tr>
```

DropDown 2: [Need to Populate values in this DropDown]

```
<tr id="prdPitch">
     <td style="text-align: left" width="20%">Product Pitched</td>
     <td style="text-align: left" width="20%"><html:select
      property="strProductPitched" style="width:180px;">
      <html:option value="">select</html:option>
      <%if(null != ProductPitchList) { %>
      <html:optionsCollection name="ProductPitchList" />
      <%} %>
      </html:select></td>
</tr>
```

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: JQuery would definitely make your life easier.

Comment: I dont know JQuery also. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple if you use jQuery

[see here for example](http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/ajax-with-struts-example/)

Here they give good example.Remember to insert jQuery related js files

include following files

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Raghu King did you saw my answer

Comment: Yes, I am Looking into it.

Comment: How to call particular Method

Comment: which one i have to use? Please suggest me.

Comment: @Raghu King  Sorry i dont know exactly about struts1 to call a method.I am working on struts2.

Comment: How to do the same in struts2

Comment: @Raghu King   in struts2 we will specify the method name directly in struts2

Comment: Yeah i know that one. is it possible to get the list from action and assign values in dropdown. how to do?

Comment: @@Raghu King in struts2 tags for select box we will directly set the list to list attribue of select box.