# How to call Action using Ajax in Strut2

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

On Continue for the below [Action call from ajax in struts1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499629/how-to-call-java-action-using-ajax)

I am trying the same with struts2.
i have tried with following code:

```
function onChangeProduct(){
  var name = $('#product').val();   
   alert(name);
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/SampleAjax/getProduct.do",  
    data: "name=" + name,  
    success: function(response){  
      // we have the response  
      $('#info').html(response);  
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });
```

}

DropDown box:

```
<s:select  name="product"  headerKey="0" headerValue="Select Product" list="#request.Product" onchange="onChangeProduct()"></s:select>
```

when i am select value from the above DropDown box and try to get value of product. i got undifined in the alert message. please help me out for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will give undefined because you had not provide id in your  tag. put **id="product"** in your tag and it will display value. Jquery will find tag using id not a name.

Comment: Thank You!!! i got value. but i am getting error on object in second alert message

Answer (score 0):

You can try with changing this:

```
var name = $('#product').val();
```

to this:

```
var name = $(this).val();
```

and add this here:

```
onchange="onChangeProduct(this.value)"></s:select>
```

complete function:

```
function onChangeProduct(val){
   var name = val;   
   alert(name);
   $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/SampleAjax/getProduct.do",  
      data: {name : name},   //<-----use this to make a dataString
      success: function(response){  
           // we have the response  
          $('#info').html(response);  
      },  
      error: function(e){  
          alert('Error: ' + e);  
      }  
   });  

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the same above, Hereby I am sharing code below,

Details.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onChangeProduct() {/* 
        var name = $('#product').val();
        alert(name);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/SampleAjax/getProduct.action",
            data : {
                prod : name
            },
            success : function(response) {
                // we have the response  
                $('#productPitch').html(response);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }); */

        name=document.getElementById("product").value;
           //document.myForm.selectedGroupId.value=groupIds;
             var  strURL="/SampleAjax/getProduct.action?prod="+name;

                          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 

                             var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                           } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 

                             var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                           }
                        xmlHttp.open('POST',strURL , true);
                        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("productPitch").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                      //document.getElementById("load3").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";


                       }
                }



                xmlHttp.send(null);


    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Details
<s:form name="sampleDto">

    <s:select name="product" id="product" headerKey="0"
        headerValue="Select Product" list="#request.Product"
        onchange="onChangeProduct()" theme="simple">
        </s:select>
</s:form>
<div id="productPitch"></div>
```

product.jsp

```
<select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <c:forEach var="listItems" items="${ProductPitch }">

            <option value="<c:out value="${listItems}" />">
                <c:out value="${listItems}" />
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Action:

```
System.out.println("Hi");
    ArrayList<String> prodPitch = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(null != getProd()){
        System.out.println(""+getProd());
        prodPitch = sampleBo.getProductPitch(getProd());
    }
    System.out.println(prodPitch.size());
        request.put("ProductPitch", prodPitch);

    return "success";
```